# Why does react-spring not repeatedly work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-spring

I am trying [react-spring](https://www.react-spring.io/) together with [useInterval](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/):

https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-water-icy6m

```
export default App = () => {
  let [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useInterval(() => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }, 1000);

  const style = useSpring({
    opacity: 1 - Math.random() / 10,
    from: { opacity: 0 + Math.random() / 10 }
  });

  return <animated.h1 style={style}>{count}</animated.h1>;
};
```

At first, I was using

```
  const style = useSpring({
    opacity: 1,
    from: { opacity: 0 }
  });
```

But I thought if the virtual DOM doesn't get any diff from previous values, then it won't re-render, so I added the `Math.random() / 10` to change it a little bit so that it can work, but it wouldn't fade in the number every one second except the very first one.  How can it be made to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the animation to start again you need to set the `reset` flag:

```
const style = useSpring({
opacity: 1,
from: { opacity: 0},
reset:true});
```

Comment: good solution.  But do you know why without it, it doesn't work? Supposedly, if it can work the first time, it should work the second time, especially if the first time is from opacity 0.053 to 0.923 and the second time is from 0.021 to 0.9832... but that's what I feel with myself and coworkers: we become the pragmatic programmers like for Ruby on Rails: we know if we type this, then something works, but nobody knows why

Comment: It doesn't work because by default they don't re-set the `from` value, so you go from 0.923 to 0.9832, which is not particularly noticeable

Comment: In fact, if you do ` 1- Math.random() ` without `/10` you'll notice it keeps animating (and it looks strangely fascinating!)

Comment: does it look like twilight zone to you? Hm... I can accept the fact that it doesn't reset... but it is kind of like, we have a loop to repeat `a = b + 1` and `b` was 10 and `a` was 11, and now `b` is `20`, oh nope, `a` is still `11` because we didn't tell it to "reset". We have to reset for it to become `21`